# C Variadic Macros __VA_ARGS__ vs ##__VA_ARGS__ in clang

Tags: c, xcode, macros, clang, variadic-macros

I have the following two macros:

```
#define F1(...) [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__]
#define F2(format, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:(format), ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

When I nest them, F1 works, but F2 fails to compile.

This code:

```
    F1(@"%@", F1(@"%@", @"a"));
    F2(@"%@", F2(@"%@", @"a"));
```

Results in the following clang errors:

```
foo.m:51:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'F2' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    F2(@"%@", F2(@"%@", @"a"));
          ^
foo.m:18:64: note: expanded from macro 'F2'
#define F2(format, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:(format), ##__VA_ARGS__]
                                                           ^
foo.m:51:15: warning: format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    F2(@"%@", F2(@"%@", @"a"));
         ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         %d
foo.m:18:64: note: expanded from macro 'F2'
#define F2(format, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:(format), ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

Note that there is no warning or error for F1, only F2 has problems.

What is going on here: is this the expected behavior or a bug in clang?

More importantly, is there a way for me to tweak F2 to get it to work. I really prefer the syntax of F2.

---

**Update**

Following @KenThomases advice I ran `clang -E -o foo.i foo.m`

```
# 1 "foo.m"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 178 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "foo.m" 2



NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"a"]]);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%@"), F2(@"%@", @"a")]);
```

I submitted this as a defect to llvm.org: [Bug 19141](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19141)

Comment: As a workaround, `#define F3(...) F2(__VA_ARGS__)`, then use `F3` in place of `F2`.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the preprocessor is not expanding the inner use of the `F2` macro. Apparently, the use of `##__VA_ARGS__` is just inserting the arguments of the outer use of `F2` verbatim and not performing further expansion.

You can have the compiler preprocess the code and it will show you what happened.  `cc -E -o foo.i foo.c`